# HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") returns new access token every time

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, .net-6.0, auth0

I am trying to write MVC application where my pages will be secured using Auth0. To render these pages I call external API to fetch data where I pass an access token.

So I have written a HttpClientHandler to attach the access token from HttpContext.

```cs
public class AuthorizationTokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AuthorizationTokenHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I observed one thing that `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync` returns a new access token every time because of that the external API cannot validate that expiry.

Access token from Run1:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImlvSlBtcnJVWlROQTN2eklsZWdqbiJ9.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.gfCX2UFCe2ARgvVP70nL1o-IYOAEgOYLcAHFYTNwlQdgDFtpq3sqBS81U6VQoinzESMkNM1euDkzbhkYU-McZq3uK03ARRIalP-iFbVxCyFfQmcpLgwTsKj-i2HgE2sUP6fhYtYVRMS-kfK5fAUBAKlAL4ILxW4vFBZIVJxG-Q9jTtm5ld8n_TkLv3SXa5NbNavGbxtfD4xggnE2_Q6dnZCKj6iAaCeMs7eRyEqzIonxbbQGvBYbZvto4y5kh21iigdkrnxDjU60TrbJCDcpShbm-IE2wzFkwpECm5eEBr5UTQh-pYESQTf6j96hfklNpHj19tS8NWhcHr_Ak7K6_w
```

Access Token from Run2:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImlvSlBtcnJVWlROQTN2eklsZWdqbiJ9.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.mnvNwc1uLuUyFsanpiu74_5sLzdt9X7vkaPO4fajsSHkDHMEFFD1M_KmUP3U-Sq9k5c4JjrYdBe8uwqgifqIjOwwgoq3PhX9geDrhw18AM6Iv9rhJ8SBlJMJqYXxpwHPqoYu8tfGgmLVLDqz8p0TjJSSDUEXBPr4f9Xqa-t8FV8G_QWJXnpXVyf4yywAxA-HKZzlNTQfdS-DoJ6XmiydkSJrowVX_SIH-2XinjszUh9rpzL1V7fOAp_Nd0_loMKE0KZ5ACaOix3Lv5AMFOd8Ayc93-p-rXTQvjL7bcLoA6tJJFqGmEQNGp6PcwFdxk7YwXEcA3T7KZ2aHyMnpxDiyg
```

Can anyone help me how to validate the expiry of token, since everytime its generating a new access token.

Comment: Before you send jwt token, you can try to use `ReadJwtToken` method in  `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` class to get the an instance of JwtSecurityToken, Then use `if (JwtSecurityToken.ValidTo < DateTime.UtcNow)` to check if token has expired.